# Browser refresh and back buttons cause problems in AJAX-based-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js

I am new to jquery as well as stack overflow.I would like your help in something that might be simple. I tried some solutions proposed but none worked for my case.

I am trying to use the History.js plugin in order to fix the back button functionality that seems to be not working with Ajax. The problem is that I can't handle the plugin properly so when I change state the URL changes and if I try to refresh the initial template disappears.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Prepare
        var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h

        if (!History.enabled) {
            // History.js is disabled for this browser.
            // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
            return false;
        }

        // Bind to StateChange Event
        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
            alert('we have a state change');
            alert(document.URL);
            if (document.URL == 'http://localhost/e-support-uop.com/') {
                alert('ok');
                $('#main_contents').load('home.php');

            }
            else {
                var State = History.getState();

                $('#main_contents').load(State.url);
            }
        });

        $('a').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the basics of the html

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <script src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
....
  <div id="main_contents">
       <!--all the content goes here and the this is the div that I want to change..-->
...
       <div id="rooms">
          <img src='images/rooms2.jpg' />
          <div class='description'>  
        <p class='description_content'>
              <a href="rooms.php" rel="rooms.php" class='img_link'>Rooms</a>
                     <!-- on click on this link I need main_contents content refresh -->  
            </p>  
        </div>  
   </div> <!--end main contents -->
</body>
```

I would like to change the contents of a div but keep back and refresh function working. The initial template should also be there.

Comment: First of all, pushState has 3 input parameters, not 4

Comment: If you put this code in a codebin or jsfiddle, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks whiteletters.I changed the , with . Matt I do not think it s a debugging issue. The code works. The problem is that I can t think a way to change the url but at the same time keep the initial template. Thanks though..

Comment: Can you please tell us how do 'rooms.php' and your ajax script look? I think you also should know that the URL you push in history stack is what you get inside your Adapter.bind, after calling getState. Why are you making an if-else statement and using in your 'if' the current browser URL. History.js provides with getState, which is the best way to manage your past URLs. Anyway, I think you should explain more so that people from the community understand what you need to resolve. good luck

Comment: The rooms.php is a simple phrase without any format..as far as the ajax script is embeded in jquery via the load command.there is no seperate ajax file..